# My anchors are not working

Tags: html, css

Here is my first project (I'm not a web dev, it's an example).
https://codepen.io/Ziratsu/pen/EWyoLN
I've put anchors in my Header, for the different parts of my portfolio, but they aren't working when I click on them..
I've put the correct "ID", I don't know why this don't work.

```
<button class="btn" id="Bouton1" type="button"><a  href="#textb">About</a></button>
```

And here is the reference of my anchor, with the same ID.

```
 <p id="textb"> Front-End Developer and UX/UI designer,</br> with practical experience in project management, branding strategy,</br> and creative direction; devoted to functional programming and information architecture.</br>Web Developer - User Experience Designer - Graphic Artist</p> </div>
```

Thank's if you take time to reply!

Comment: You are supposed to click the link not the button

Comment: Have you tried removing the `button` element? Maybe it does not work because you're not actually clicking the `a` element

Comment: please change the id on link target you are calling #textb from every button. Example

<button class="btn" id="Bouton3" type="button"><a href="#conteneur3">Contact</a></button>

Comment: i have tried on jsfiddle..and its working.!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a anchor tag instead of a button:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#textb">About</a>
```

You can use the btn class to make it look like a button if you're using bootstrap, which I asumed because of the btn class.

Comment: I don't know how ! Tell me ahaha

Comment: Look for the answer on the page and click on the "check" symbol to accept the answer, it's under the up-down arrow.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `button` element:

```
<a  href="#textb">About</a>
```

Just design the `a` if you want to make it have a button-like appearance